# Compile rygel for yocto with plugins

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm using bitbake to compile rygel for yocto from the meta-openembedded layer, with the plugins mpris and gst-launch.

As per the [PACKAGECONFIG docs](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PACKAGECONFIG), I created a bbappend file and added the following:

```
EXTRA_OECONF = "--disable-introspection \
                --disable-tracker-plugin \
                --with-media-engine=gstreamer \
                --enable-mpris-plugin \
                --enable-gst-launch-plugin"

PR = "r1"
```

It compiles and installs, but has no plugins.

The append shows up when I run `bitbake-layers show-appends`, so at least bitbake is finding it. After running bitbake the directory `tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/rygel/0.26.1-r1/image/usr/lib/rygel-2.6/plugins/` is populated. Then when I run the image `/usr/lib/rygel-2.6/` contains an `engines` dir and nothing else.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: did you tried += after the oeconf

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your read all the way down to "If you want to change an existing PACKAGECONFIG block, you can do so one of two ways:".

From a bbappend, just do

PACKAGECONFIG_append = " mpris gst-launch"

Comment: OOoooh I though that was for if you want to create new PACKAGECONFIG options, and that EXTRA_OECONF was for invoking those options. Either way, I tried with that PACKAGECONFIG_append and the plugins directory is still empty.

Comment: Did you include the leading whitespace?  What git branches?

Comment: Leading white space yes. Branch is jethro, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the recipe do_install, they remove some of the engines and plugins files.  This might be the reason you do not see them in your image.

```
do_install_append() {
       # Remove .la files for loadable modules
       rm -f ${D}/${libdir}/rygel-${LIBV}/engines/*.la
       rm -f ${D}/${libdir}/rygel-${LIBV}/plugins/*.la
}
```

Comment: After running bitbake, there are no *.la files in the plugins dir, but there are the following:

`ls tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/rygel/0.26.1-r2/image/usr/lib/rygel-2.6/plugins
external.plugin       librygel-gst-launch.so    librygel-mpris.so    media-export.plugin  playbin.plugin
gst-launch.plugin     librygel-media-export.so  librygel-playbin.so  mediathek.plugin     ruih.plugin
librygel-external.so  librygel-mediathek.so     librygel-ruih.so     mpris.plugin`

Maybe I just need to write a do_install_append to copy them over...

Comment: Oh, I think you're installing the rygel package but not any of the package plugins.  Check the feeds, you'll see every plugin goes into a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

your compiling plugins successfully and not able to see in board(rootfs)? if yes please add below line in your `.bbappend` file. '

`FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*"`
this will add all your compiled plugins to your rootfs image.